# Why can't assign I <? extends Type> to <Type>?

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion, extends, bounded-wildcard

The following statements:

```
URLClassLoader ucl = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class<URLClassLoader> uclc = ucl.getClass();
```

fail with error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#2-of ? extends URLClassLoader> to Class<URLClassLoader>
```

Why do I need a cast, here?

I found several posts explaining why You can't do the reverse (assign T to a ), but that's (kind of) obvious and understood.

NOTE: I am coding this under eclipse Luna, so I don't know if it's a Luna Quirk or if there's something I really dont understand in generics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Covariance vs contravariance vs invariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

- `Class<? extends URLClassLoader>` is **invariant**.

As a result,

`Class<? extends URLClassLoader>` is **not a subtype** of `Class<URLClassLoader>`

---

In Java a variable can hold a reference of an instance of **same type or subtype**.

Hence,

```
Class<URLClassLoader> uclc = ucl.getClass();
```

is **invalid**.

On the other hand,

```
Class<? extends URLClassLoader> uclc = ucl.getClass();
```

would be **valid**.

Comment: Can you eloborate why `Class<? extends T>` (or `Class<?>`) is not a subtype of `Class<T>`? I think it is.

Comment: @swiki: Try to think in terms of collections. Do you think List<? extends Number> should be assignable to List<Integer>? This will lead to type safety problems and isn't allowed. The opposite assignment is allowed though.

Comment: Read this fantastic explanation: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ503

Comment: @skiwi: types are ranges of values. Generic types are ranges of types. `Class<? extends T>` is the type that encompasses all the types that extend from `T`

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't assign I <? extends Type> to <Type>?

Because actually `<? extends Type>` is a supertype of `<Type>`! Let's follow the specification.

[4.10.2 Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2):

> Given a generic type declaration C<F<sub>1</sub>,...,F<sub>n</sub>>, the direct supertypes of the parameterized type C<T<sub>1</sub>,...,T<sub>n</sub>> are all of the following:
>
> - C<S<sub>1</sub>,...,S<sub>n</sub>>, where S<sub>i</sub> contains T<sub>i</sub>.

[4.5.1. Type Arguments of Parameterized Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

> A type argument T<sub>1</sub> is said to contain another type argument T<sub>2</sub>, written T<sub>2</sub> <= T<sub>1</sub>, if the set of types denoted by T<sub>2</sub> is provably a subset of the set of types denoted by T<sub>1</sub> under the reflexive and transitive closure of the following rules:
>
> - T <= ? extends T

We therefore know that since `? extends URLClassLoader` contains `URLClassLoader`, `Class<? extends URLClassLoader>` is a supertype of `Class<URLClassLoader>`.

Because a [narrowing reference conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) is not permitted within an [assignment context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), a compilation error occurs.

Also note that this means the reverse assignment is permitted:

```
Class<URLClassLoader> concrete = URLClassLoader.class;
Class<? extends URLClassLoader> wildcard = concrete;
```